# Can I be a Maths Teacher?

Tags: graduate-education

I'm 26 and hold a 2.2 degree in Biomedical Science from a British university. I took my A Levels in Biology and Chemistry but only got an AS Level in Maths and Art. My work background is that I have been a carer for family members for many years. I would love to pursue Maths teaching but I am unsure whether I would be accepted onto the programmes and whether I should complete an A Level in Maths with a view to apply for PGCE or Schools Direct Route in 2015.

Comment: It appears you have asked this both here and academia.SE.

Comment: Which forum is my question most suited to?

Comment: Is your question (a) here are my backgrounds, do you think I can succeed as a math teacher? or (b) I want to become a math teacher, here are my backgrounds, what are the bureaucratic details I must take care of in order to become a math teacher? or (c) here are my backgrounds, I am thinking about becoming a math teacher, is it a good idea?

Comment: Voting to close; I think WW has pretty clearly outlined why it's unclear what is being asked.

Comment: If OP shares these details and clarifies the question, this might be reasonable. At what point would it be judicious to assume this clarification is not forthcoming and close the question? (I'll hold off on voting for now.)

Comment: The question at http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/28990/64 currently has three answers and two votes to close.

Comment: Hi Willie Wong, my question is more suited to the second question you described.

Comment: @HennyGaskin You question is not really suited to any stack exchange site, as it asks for details that can be found by searching on a single website. The world at large is not a good source of information on bureaucratic requirements. I'd suggest you look at the government teaching website, which details all the possible routes into teaching in the UK.

Comment: Sorry, I've now noticed this is a somewhat old question.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematics and teaching it is not a suitable job for everybody. Math is a love and if you haven't got a love for mathematics it would be boring for you and your students.

If you have huge interest to work with mathematical subjects, you would be the happiest person in your circumstance. Elsewhere it is not good idea to make it as your job.

Comment: "Mathematics and teaching it is not suitable job for anybody." I sincerely hope that you meant "Teaching math is not suitable for everybody, but is suitable for some." Otherwise, this entire site is in vain!

Comment: "if you haven't got a love for mathematics it would be boring for you and your students. " This is so true. It always worries me when I see future teachers who don't seem to care about math. I hate to see the circle of violence against math continue...

Comment: @brendansullivan07 I think math can not be good job. It is a love and can not be seen as regular job. One person may do any job even if don't like it. But for Math it is impossible that you hate it and try to teach it. It will be torture.

Comment: -1. "I think math can not be good job."  I disagree.  I think that being a mathematician or a mathematics educator can be a good job.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche  I am agree with you only person love math therefore it would be the best job. But when anybody are looking for any job, Math is not good job just for being employed only.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I think there are some English translation issues and opinions are misinterpreted/misrepresented. I believe that we're all saying, "Math (and teaching) is not necessarily the right job for everyone. You have to want to do it."